# visibility: hidden working differently on different browsers

Tags: css, animation, delay, visibility, fading

I have a question that might sound stupid, but here it goes anyways.

For starters, here is the website I'm creating.
www.redshedproductionsllc.com

I have an animation running on an h1 element on my website that fades in after a delay. The problem was is that the text showed before the animation started, so it kind of had a glitchy start. I found a workaround that works flawlessly on chrome, but not on any other browser. The element simply stays hidden. Here is my CSS.

```
#fading1 {

 animation: fadein 4s;
 -moz-animation: fadein 4s; /* Firefox */
 -webkit-animation: fadein 4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
 -o-animation: fadein 4s; /* Opera */
}

#fading2 {

  visibility: hidden;
  animation: fadein 4s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 4s; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadein -4s; /* Opera */

  -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;

  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /*FF 5+*/
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /*Not implemented yet*/
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /*IE 10+*/
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; /*when the spec is finished*/
}
```

Check it out on chrome, then check it out on firefox or safari. Chrome fades in flawlessly, while the other two stay hidden. Please help!!!

Comment: Have you tried using `opacity` ?

Comment: I just tried it right after I posted this. Works flawlessly. Thanks a ton!!! :D

Comment: Keep in mind `opacity` is not a drop-in replacement for `visibility`. If you want your element to be non-interactive when hidden, `opacity` will leave you disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no such thing as moz-prefixed animation-delay. Having `-moz-animation-delay: 2s` is unneccessary.  I'm not sure why it is working in chrome and not Firefox, but I have a feeling that the animation of visibility doesn't work well in all browsers.

It would make more sense to me to fade it in from `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1` over three seconds, but make the first two seconds the delay, keeping the opacity at 0.

```
@keyframes fadein {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    66% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    66% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.fade{
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s;
    animation: fadein 3s;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1za7ay0v/2/)

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I ended up switching visibility: hidden with opacity: 0 and it worked flawlessly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Remember that `opacity` is not a drop-in replacement for `visibility` if you want your element to be non-interactive when hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I am  not very sure but you have to use something like this:

So the thing is, you have to specify certain functions of CSS for each and every browser, so you should do like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    66% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}


-moz-boxshadow
```

Read MDN guides for these prefixes.
Hope it helps! :)